# Detecting changes when using multiple VCS roots in TeamCity

Tags: teamcity

I have a build configuration that uses sources from multiple repositories. Thus, changes from all those repos go to the product. But in the process I want to know which specific repos had any changes.  I couldn't find anything in the build parameters.  Is there any way to get this info in the build process?
Thanks,
Zura

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you've probably already come to your own conclusions on this because it seems to be standard TeamCity functionality you're asking about, but here are my notes based on my brief time using TeamCity for the sake of completeness:

- A build configuration can have multiple VCS roots attached to it, and by default will start probing each root for new changes every 60 seconds
- Once changes are detected for one or more of the roots, the build configuration will show "Pending(*n*)" next to it where *n* is the number of changes it's found.
- If you click the triangle next to the Pending message, you see details of who committed the change a comment, and a filecount.
- If you click the filecount, it will popup a list of the files, and the name and revision of the VCS root it came from.
- When the build is triggered, it will remember all this change detail so you can go back later and query which changes were used in each build execution, including which VCS root and revision they originated from.

So, changes from multiple VCS roots are interleaved with each other and easy to trace.  You mention "build parameters" which is also useful, and logged, however it's more about the state in which the build agent itself runs in such as filesystem paths, environment variables or parameters passed specifically into the build configuration.